# What is the term used for stronger heart beats at average bpm?

Tags: nutrition, side-effects

Some people after drinking energy drinks, coffee and/or some mental illness medication feel their hearts beating stronger or louder but at the same bpm as without stimulants.

What is the term used to describe this? Palpitation? I've always thought that was for faster beats.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, palpitations is the correct term. Another term for it is [ectopic beats](https://www.nlm.nih.gov/medlineplus/ency/article/001100.htm), which includes the sensation of skipped or irregular beats and occasional forceful beats. If the beats are a regular rhythm but consistent and forceful, they're more likely due to [systolic hypertension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systolic_hypertension) and generally wouldn't be called palpitations (though calling them that wouldn't be wrong per se).

Another interesting cause is what's known as [water hammer pulse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watson's_water_hammer_pulse), but that's a very different pattern and doesn't seem to be what you're describing.